# How to change occurence in same line with Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I recently watch a tutorial on youtube. The guy somehow can change the same word in a same line on visual studio code. Is there any shortcut to do so? Or maybe it's an extension?

Comment: with `Ctrl+D` you can add an additional cursor to the same text and then type the new content or first `Arrow` to remove the selection and keep Multi Cursor

Comment: Thank you, eventhough that will change the occurence in all line on one file

Comment: if you are not specific what you want you do not get a specific answer

Answer (score 0):

It is **occurrence**. You can add keymap for it just search for "occurrence".

You can "add next occurrence" something like that and it will select next occurrences to your selection and you can change it.

I have same thing in PHPStorm, it is called something like "Add Next Occurrences".